# Getting field name from Bindable fieldId

Tags: android-databinding

I'm writing an app in android using databinding. I'm using `@Bindable` ([BaseObservable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html)) annotation to notify the property change on my properties. I have a very simple question, Using Bindable make android generate `fieldId` but is there a way to get the field names from these ids? (Something like `getResources().getResourceName(resourceId)` but for binding resources)

**Longer Version**

I'm using `CouchbaseLite` and `AndroidDataBinding` on a project. I want to implement a model class which contains all my fields inside a HashMap and in the meantime implements `BaseObservable`, Since `BaseObservable` requires fieldId to notify the property change I have to send the fieldId on my setters, But I also don't want to have fieldId's on my HashMap because It's gonna make my json docs unreadable. So I'm looking for a way to either reach the fieldName from fieldId or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

```
DataBindingUtil.convertBrIdToString(bindingResourceId);
```